# How to handle player actions in a multithreaded gameserver

Tags: multiplayer, mmo, multithreading

I'm working on a multiplayer game, and today I implemented basic ["spatial hashing"](https://conkerjo.wordpress.com/2009/06/13/spatial-hashing-implementation-for-fast-2d-collisions/) in my entity-component-system.

Before implementing that algorithm, I was sending players actions to all connected players :

```
public void onPlayerMovement()(auto ref PlayerMovementMessage message, ClientSocket socket)
{
    this.m_gameServer.sendToAll(message);
}
```

My code is now :

```
public void onPlayerMovement()(auto ref PlayerMovementMessage message, ClientSocket socket)
{
    auto entity = this.m_gameServer.findEntity(socket);

    auto nearbyEntities = this.m_gameServer.world.getNearbyEntities(entity.get!PositionComponent().bucket)
        .filter!(e => e.hasComponent!PlayerComponent()).array();

    if(nearbyEntities.length)
    {
        this.m_gameServer.sendTo(nearbyEntities, message);
    }
}
```

As you can see im now calling `this.m_gameServer.world.getNearbyEntities()` from SpatialHashingSystem.d to get nearby players.

onPlayerMovement function is called by class GameServer.d in a new thread, so it might be called before SpatialHashingSystem.d executes his algorithm, 
therefore calling getNearbyEntities() directly returns invalid data.

What can I do at this point ? Event system ? isnt that bad for a real time game ?

Thanks